# Passing a hook as a prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it acceptable / common to pass in a React Hook as a prop to another Component?

Or are they meant to only belong within the component it is declared in?

The following is just an example to illustrate what I mean by passing it as

a prop from the Parent Component to the Child parent.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const Parent = () => {

  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return <div>
    Current count is {count}
    <Child setCount={setCount} /> // passing a hook set call as a prop to child
  </div>
}

const Child = ({setCount}) => {
  setCount(10) // using the hook set call
  return (
    <div>
      Some Child Text
    </div>
  );
};

export default Child;
```

Comment: ya its possible. its simple like function call

Comment: That's perfectly fine, you're actually supposed to do that.

Comment: in fact, it is a pattern to pass `set` hook to child to keep all the state in parent, if you are not using a state management library like Redux

Comment: This will rerender the children when setCount function changes but this is okay if performance is still good.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`setCount` is not a hook, it is just another function, So you can pass it as a prop. You can also think of the output of `useMemo` or `useCallback`, these can be passed as a prop.

`useState` is a hook, `useCallback` is a hook, or even for a matter any *function*, which encapsulates other hooks, these should not be passed as prop.

Why?

To answer this first think of why would you want to pass the hook as a prop? The benefit of passing the hook as a prop will be that you can conditionally pass another hook / skip the call.
**But in the case of hooks, It should not be called conditionally. So there is no point. of passing it as a prop, Just import it and use it.**

Comment: Insightful assessment. So it's okay to pass a hook as long as it's a required prop and called unconditionally.

Comment: @jchook you are misinterpreting the answer, `setCount` is not a hook, it is a function which was returned from the `useState` hook, so if you pass `setCount` as prop you are not passing hook as a prop but a function

Comment: I don't actually fully agree with your statement. As an example let say I have the same UI component in different places in my app, and these two components uses two different custom hooks with the same interface. If I inject these hooks as props I could reuse the UI part.

Comment: @AbdellahElMennani you can directly import the hook function, why do you need to pass it as a prop?

Comment: As I explained before, this is in case you want the UI to be the same but the business logic is different. I think it is called polymorphism.

Comment: @AbdellahElMennani, I was just thinking about it (one UI and different hooks with the same interface) and I was wondering if it could cause any issue

Comment: @AbdellahElMennani passing hook as prop means passing the same hook / not extending or creating a copy of it, hooks are tightly attached to the lifecycle of the component, consider hypothetically you shared `useEffect` now which component lifecycle will attach to. Instead, you can create a separate common hook file, which will accept some arguments, you can now directly import this hook in your two different components and use it directly.

Comment: @Ashish, What if the required effect is different in both components but the UI is the same? Let's say make requests to different APIs

Comment: @AlexanderVidaurreArroyo pull out the logic in a custom hook, pass arguments handle things conditionally, import the hook in both the components and pass component-specific flag as argument from both the components

Answer (score 0):

Your example is totally fine and can be used. **setCount** is just a function. From your example, the state belongs to the parent component. However, its value will come from another component API.

The same would happen if you change the child component in your example for a regular `<button onClick={} />`.

I know that this example probably doesn't match your real case implementation. I'd only suggest you pay attention to how the child component API is designed in order to make the parent not tightly coupled to the child.